# Copy only specific text from a file to another

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression, clipboard

I'm working on a txt file that's structured like this:

```
; $16
    dc.b    $FF

; $17
    dc.b    $FA
    dc.b    $65, $05
    dc.b    $F6
    dc.w    $0032   ; => Event1
    dc.b    $FF

; $18
    dc.b    $F4
    dc.b    $0F
    dc.b    "text"
    dc.b    $FC
    dc.b    "more text"
    dc.b    $FD
    dc.b    "more and more text"
    dc.b    $FD
    dc.b    "more and more and more text"
```

What I'm looking for is a way to copy all the text included between all the quotation marks of the file in a new txt file, like this:

```
text
more text
more and more text
more and more and more text
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is expected, that you show some effort on your own. Anything you have tried, yet? If you are completely new to the topic: Read `man grep` and apply very simple regular expression [(a quick quide)](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-12).

Comment: It's a short awk one-liner, using double quote as the field separator, print the second field if the current line has more than one field.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(").*(")' txt
```

`P` uses Perl compatible regular expressions and `o` prints only what matches.

Output:

```
"text"
"more text"
"more and more text"
"more and more and more text"
```

Comment: A regex that omits the quotes would be `"\K[^"]+`